# How to use Compass/Codekit with Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, codekit

I just created my first test site with Jekyll and am hosting it on GitHub Pages.

I've been playing around with it, but I'm having a hard time figuring out the best way to set up CodeKit to work with Jekyll so that it does code injection on the _site/css file and also saves the changes on the /sitename/css file so that the style changes are reflected on the hosted site on GitHub Pages (which re-output the file based on the CSS from the parent directory.

So far, I figured out that I can work locally by going into config.rb and changing

```
css_dir = "css"
```

to

```
css_dir = "/_site/css"
```

and then changing it back when I want to push to GitHub.

This is extremely janky though, so I figured someone else had a better way to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Start your codekit project from within your jekyll project's root directory (ie: the path from which you would run `$ jekyll build --watch` to generate your static site).
2. In the codekit project settings, go to the **Browser Refreshing** menu, and in the Website Root Subpath field, type the destination where jekyll outputs the static site (which is `_site` by default).

This will work whether or not you are using CSS pre-processors (sass, scss, less).